# Get coefficients of a linear regression in Tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

I've done a simple linear regression in Tensorflow. How can I know what are the coefficients of the regression? 
I've read the docs but I cannot find it anywhere! (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor)

**EDIT** Code example

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Declare list of features, we only have one real-valued feature
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
  # Build a linear model and predict values
  W = tf.get_variable("W", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
  b = tf.get_variable("b", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
  y = W * features['x'] + b
  # Loss sub-graph
  loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - labels))
  # Training sub-graph
  global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
  optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
  train = tf.group(optimizer.minimize(loss),
                   tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))
  # EstimatorSpec connects subgraphs we built to the
  # appropriate functionality.
  return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      predictions=y,
      loss=loss,
      train_op=train)

estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
# define our data sets
x_train = np.array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
y_train = np.array([0., -1., -2., -3.])
x_eval = np.array([2., 5., 8., 1.])
y_eval = np.array([-1.01, -4.1, -7, 0.])
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)

# train
estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
# Here we evaluate how well our model did.
train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print("train metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

Comment: Can you post your code so that we see how what exactly have you done? Difficult to answer generally...

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm following the example that is in the tutorial example in https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started

Comment: You are not using [`tf.estimator.LinearRegressor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/LinearRegressor), but rather implementing your own estimator, right? (which is equivalent to a linear regressor).

Comment: @jdehesa I've also tried with that option. In that case, how can I get the coefficient values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: As [Jason Ching](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906456) points out, there have been some changes after this answer was posted. There are now the estimator methods [`get_variable_names`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_names) and [`get_variable_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#get_variable_value), and the estimator weights do not seem to be automatically added to `tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES` anymore.

---

Estimators are designed to work basically as a black box, so there is no direct API to retrieve the weights. Even if, as in your case, you are the one defining the model (as opposed to using a preexisting model), you do not have a direct access to the parameters from the estimator object.

That said, you can still retrieve the variables back through other means. If you know the names of the variables, one option is to simply get them from the graph object with [`get_operation_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_operation_by_name) or [`get_tensor_by_name`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#get_tensor_by_name). A more practical and general option is to use a collection. Either when you call [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable) or after that, calling [`tf.add_to_collection`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/add_to_collection), you can put the model variables under a common collection name for later retrieval. If you look at how a `tf.estimator.LinearRegressor` is actually built (search for the function `linear_model` in [this module](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/python/feature_column/feature_column.py)), all model variables are added to both `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` and `tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES`. This is (presumably, I haven't really checked) common to all the available canned estimators, so usually when using one of those you should be able to simply do:

```
model_vars = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES)
```

It is preferable that you use `tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES` in this case instead of `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES`, which has a more general purpose and is likely to contain other unrelated variables as well.

Comment: my tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES is empty.  I am using this:

`print([(v, linear_regressor.get_variable_value(v)) for v in linear_regressor.get_variable_names()])`

Comment: @JasonChing Thank you, I have updated the answer (or feel free to post another one yourself and I'll upvote it and refer to it). Apparently they made a few changes since the answer was posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
LR.train(input_fn=train_input_data,steps = 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    last_check = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(tf_data)
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(last_check + '.meta')
    print (last_check +'.meta')
    saver.restore(sess, last_check)
    ######
    Model_variables = tf.GraphKeys.MODEL_VARIABLES
    Global_Variables = tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
    ######
    all_vars = tf.get_collection(Model_variables)
    # print (all_vars)
    for i in all_vars:
        print (str(i) + '  -->  '+ str(i.eval()))
```